# How should I test this method using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to rspec and ruby and am having trouble writing a test for the following method using doubles etc.

```
def choices player1_choice, player2_choice
  @choices_array =  [player1_choice, player2_choice]
end
```

I have tried several ways but can't get it right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic unit test for this method.  You would not need to use a double for this method.

```
describe YourClassName do

  context "#choices" do

    it "should return an array with 2 player choices" do
      player1_choice = "a"
      player2_choice = "b"
      output = choices(player1_choice, player2_choice)
      expect(output.count).to eq(2)
      expect(output[0]).to eq(player1_choice)
      expect(output[1]).to eq(player2_choice)
    end

  end

end
```

Doubles/stubs are usually used around methods/objects that contain complex operations such as a network connection, integrating with a 3rd party library without implementation details, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher is right in that you don't need to use doubles for this. However, I disagree with his use of more than one assertion per test. This is generally considered bad practice and I think it is unnecessary here.

Also, what exactly do you want to test? The method you have written is unusual. Anyway, without further knowledge of your intentions, it's impossible to know how best to proceed. However, here's a one-assertion test that essentially provides the same test coverage as Christopher's multiple assertions:

```
it "returns an array of two player_choices" do
  result = ["a", "b"]
  expect(choices("a", "b")).to eq result
end
```

Comment: It's true that it's better to just expect the whole array, but it's definitely not true that a test must only have one expectation. That's a pointless meme that results in bloated and slow test suites.

Comment: I agree that some of the expectations are a bit redundant, but for completeness, it is better to check each object at each position to verify the validity and order of the array's elements. I don't agree that one expectation is the norm. It might be a guideline but more complicated integration tests will likely require 2+ expectations.